# Changing routing's default parameter name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I used to keep the default routing, but a conflict caused me to change the default parameter `id` to `paramid`.

Normally, I was using code like this in a view:

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Suivis", new {o.ID})
```

And this in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) { ... }
```

But it doesn't work anymore, it forces me to use:

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Suivis", new {paramid = o.ID})
```

This is the code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int paramidid) { ... }
```

My question is: Why do I now have to specify the parameter name in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original action:

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Suivis", new {o.ID})
```

The anonymous type was being created with the same name (ID).  Since you had to change what the route is expecting from a parameter of ID, to paramid - when you attempt to pass in o.ID, which is translating to new {ID = o.ID}, the route isn't matching because it's looking for paramid.

If it's a viewmodel, you could change the property to be paramid -

```
@Url.Action("Edit", "Suivis", new {o.paramid})
```

and it will work again - but this may be more trouble than it's worth.